# Jquery callback function and variable scope

Tags: jquery

Is the below Jquery code a valid one? Specifically, when callback functions are called from fun2(), will the variables a and b be in scope?

Some details on how callback functions and variables are handled in this scenario will be helpful.

```
function fun1(a, b)
{
    var c1 = function () {
        console.log(a);
    }

    var c2 = function () {
        console.log(b);
    }

    fun2(c1, c2);
}

function fun2(callback1, callback2)
{
    //Display a modal and invoke callback functions based on button click
    $('#btnOk').click(function(){
        callback1();
    });

    $('#btnCancel').click(function(){
        callback2();
    });
}
```

This code works as expected, but I am not sure how the variable scopes are handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes `a` in `[[Scope]]` of `c1` and `b` in `[[Scope]]` of `c2`